# Can I restrict method parameters to only certain Enum members?

Tags: java, interface, enums, enumset

Is there a way to restrict a method to only take certain members of an enumeration.  Let's say you had an enumeration of military and enlisted ranks.  If I wanted a function that only could take officer ranks and another that could only take enlisted ranks, I don't think there's a way to do that in Java, is there?

Comment: could you post some code on what you're trying to do? Got lost readying. Sorry.

Comment: Something like SecurityEnumSet = any of { A B C } and MonkeyEnumSet = { B D E } where the type of { A B C D E } are all SpecialEnumType ?

Comment: If you want to guarantee it with the type system, then they need to be distinct types, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only option is to use distinct enums, as a method taking an enum as a parameter will take any of its values at compile time.

IDEs help with the typing.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  The IDE is not helping.  Eclipse 3.6 refuses to find the enumerations I want to use even when its statically imported into the class where I'm calling it or into the class containing the relavent methods.  I was hoping because they were contained in EnumSets that I could use that, but i guess not.

Comment: I did indeed put the various enums in an interface, who has a inner class that holds the enums data.  They each have a constructor that calls that class and a getter method that gets it which is part of the interface they all implement.  Its the best I could do, but its still a lot of typing.  Word to the wise, avoid static anything in enums.